# Problem during trying to follow answer on Review Late Answers

Tags: bug, late-answers, follow-posts

While I was reviewing Late Answers post, I got to know something weird on Stack Overflow.

I pressed the <kbd>follow</kbd> button in a random question as shown in the image:

[image: Following answer bug on Review of Late Answers]

I was unable to follow it from the review queue. But I did it successfully by going to the link directly.

[image: Following answer on the original thread works]

**Important Points:**

1. I've tried clearing the browser cache & tried in Incognito mode as well.
2. Other browsers are having the same issue.

I wonder if it's a bug lurking around.

Comment: Generally, doing anything outside of reviewing in the review queues is undefined -- I avoid it. If I'm interested in a post, I'll open it in a new tab and do what I want there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think the **follow** feature shouldn't be visible to the reviewers.

Comment: At the very least it should show an error message instead of just failing silently.

Comment: 100%. What some or others of us think should or shouldn't be done in the review queue is irrelevant- this is clearly a bug if it's just failing silently. If it officially "shouldn't" be used, then the fix can be removing it, but that notion doesn't make it less broken now.

Comment: This has already been reported at [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350306/289905), [Unable to follow while in Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350648/289905), and [Clicking the follow link from the review queue does nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350813/289905). A fix is already planned. This isn’t an issue that just affects Stack Overflow, but the entire network.